# How can I hook into the current FormsAuthenticationModule in a Medium Trust environment?

Tags: asp.net, events, forms-authentication, httpmodule, medium-trust

I've got an HttpModule in my application that hooks into the FormsAuthenticationModule's Authenticate event with the following code:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    FormsAuthenticationModule faModule =
        (FormsAuthenticationModule)context.Modules["FormsAuthentication"];
    faModule.Authenticate +=
        new FormsAuthenticationEventHandler(faModule_Authenticate);
}
```

Unfortunately, the call to context.Modules fails because the app needs to run in a medium-trust environment.  Is there another way that I can hook into this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a tough one - you can't even access the Modules collection from within your Global application file.

You could try calling your custom code from the AuthenticateRequest handler in Global:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call your module's code here..
}
```

You can't grab your custom module from the collection, either, so you'd need a static reference to your module's library.

Other than granting the AspNetHostingPermission ([as detailed for other permissions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998341.aspx#paght000020_oledbpermission)) to your site in the machine level web.config, I'm out of ideas!

Comment: If you check the Modules property in the HttpApplication class in System.Web via Reflector, you can see the CAS demand for a High trust level.  Unfortunately, I know my hoster's response to asking: "We have these WONDERFUL VPS/Dedicated servers!" :(

Comment: Yes, locked-down hosting is a problem - and I'm guessing your module is 3rd party?

Comment: No, it's my own, so I can put the code somewhere else, was just hoping to keep it separated.